# Does a mini PCIe to PCIe slot adapter exist?

Tags: pci-express, minipci

I know there are similar questions to mine, but in this case I need to insert a mini PCIe card into a PCIe slot.

Summing it up, I have a mini-ITX motherboard with a PCIe x16 slot and I have a mini PCIe HDCP capture card.

Is there any way to insert this mini PCIe into the PCIe x16 slot? An adapter would be fine.

Comment: It’s commonly called PCIe to Mini-PCIe adapter, not the other way. That being said, out of curiosity: what’s an “HDMI card”?

Comment: @DanielB here's the card I have: http://www.magewell.com/pro-capture-mini-hdmi

Comment: That is a HDCP capture cards. I edited it in. (Just HDMI is ike saying I have a 'copper thing' rather than a 'copper tube').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapters do exist and are quite cheap. As little as $10 on eBay.
Mini-PCIe to PCIe-1x or PCIe-4x are most common and will fit in a PCIe-16x slot. (mini-PCIe can't  have 16 PCIe lanes anyway.)
There are also "sets" consisting of an adapter and a min-PCIe WLAN card. You could take the WLAN card out and replace it with your capture card, because the converter is generic and will work with outer mini-PCIe cards.

Please note: mini-PCIe devices can use either PCIe or USB to make the connection. Be careful to buy a converter compatible with the variant your capture card uses. Not every converter can handle both variants.

Comment: Thanks. I really had already seen them on eBay but I didn't knew they could work with my card too. Already requested one.